# Parsing local XML file throws unterminated entity ref error

Tags: android

When I try to parse my xml file

```
<item>
<year>1990</year>
<chapter>Chapter 1</chapter>
</item>
```

From a URL, it works fine, but when I try to load from a local file, it throws a SAXParseException unterminated entity ref error.

Comment: I saw this, when loading from a resource, and it looks like the real problem was I was loading the wrong resource.  Not sure why/how yet, but calling `resources.getResourceEntryName(id)` helped verify that was the case.

Comment: ... my problem was I was loading a resource from my app, when I wanted to load it from my test case.  Subclassing `InstrumentationTestCase` helped; see http://dorothydorothy.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/reading-a-file-from-an-android-test-project/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see any error..

But maybe the XML declaration is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Are you sure you're reading the file correctly?

Comment: Yea, I have the XML Declaration up there too, I ended up not using the SAXParser, and ended up going with the XMLPullParser. I'm not really sure why it wouldn't read it though.